# Can IntelliJ IDEA offer proper Scala assistance with Scalate's flavor of Jade / Pug?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, pug, scalate

I have a lot of Jade templates that are created with [Scalate](http://scalate.github.io/scalate/documentation/jade.html). While you can tell IntelliJ to use its Pug plugin to parse them, it's not familiar with Scala code, which prevents it from giving much code help other than basic syntax highlighting (and lots of false positives on errors).

Is there any way to get the plugin to recognize the Scala code within Scalate's Jade templates?

Otherwise, can IntelliJ highlight *.jade files with the Pug plugin, but automatically disable all inspections for all of the files? I see you can disable these on a per-file level, but if the plugin doesn't work properly, I'd love to have to not even try to save my computer, and to not show thousands of irrelevant errors.

Comment: IntelliJ Scala plugin does not have special support for this. There is a request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-4946

Comment: Just what I was looking for! In the meantime, can I prevent IntelliJ from checking syntax by default for all Jade files? See last part of question.